# Why project cannot find references for WebJobs.Core?

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

Following [this](https://github.com/christopheranderson/azure-webjobs-dotnet-core-sample) I created a console .Net Core 2.1 application, and I'm using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Core NuGet v. 3.0.0-beta5. For some reason the project can't compile as it says it cannot find the assemblies. Why on earth?
[image]

Comment: Try to see the error in Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Core nuget, expand it. It can be something like it's refering an assembly which you reference directly but from different version.

Comment: I did, there is no error there. I don't even know why VS marks it with yellow warning sign

Comment: Sometimes a simple VS close/open solves it. Try also to remove that version and add the stable one, I saw both dependencies and there are a considerable number of addtions from the stable version to 3.0.0-beta5.

Comment: Yes, I did the well known Microsoft unique technique "close/open" and nothing happened. Well the guy from GitHub uses .net core 2.0 and WebJobs Core v. 3.0.0-beta1-10871. I even tried to replicate his versions with me and it didn't work as well...

Comment: Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard). The problem could be the compatibility between .net standard 2.0 and .net core 2.1.

Comment: I changed my project to .net core 2.0 and WebJobs.Core to 2.2.0 and still doesn't find the assemblies

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178198/discussion-between-rui-fernandes-and-nmrlqa4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you do not need to install [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Core/3.0.0-beta5) NuGet v. 3.0.0-beta5.

You could just try to install [**Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs/3.0.0-beta5) version 3.0.0-beta5. Then it will work.

This `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs` package contains the runtime assemblies for `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host`. It also adds rich diagnostics capabilities which makes it easier to monitor the WebJobs in the dashboard. For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki).